# GeoDjango: raise GDALException('Could not open the datasource at "%s"' % ds_input)

Tags: geodjango

When i take the example following the GeoDjango tutorial at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/

when I use GeoDjango’s DataSource interface, and got the problem:

```
$ python manage.py shell
>>> import os
>>> import world
>>> world_shp=os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(world.__file__), 'data', 'TM_WORLD_BOARDERS-0.3.shp'))
>>> from django.contrib.gis.gdal import DataSource
>>> ds = DataSource(world_shp)
Traceback (most recent call last):
....
packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/datasource.py", line 74, in __init__
   raise GDALException('Could not open the datasource at "%s"' % ds_input)
django.contrib.gis.gdal.error.GDALException: Could not open the datasource at "/home/robert/PycharmProjects/geodjango/world/data/TM_WORLD_BOARDERS-0.3.shp"
```

I have used ogrinfo to check the TM_WORLD_BOARDERS-0.3.shp, that is ok. But datasource could not open it.

Comment: do you have valid .shp with other mandatory files (like .shx, .dbf)?

Comment: using ogrinfo valid the .shp file: $ ogrinfo  ./TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp
INFO: Open of `./TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.
1: TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3 (Polygon)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error when trying to import a .shp file that came in a folder with other related files (eg .shx index file and .dbf attribute format). Importing the parent directory rather than the .shp file itself seemed to work.

eg

```
# ds = DataSource('/tmp/parent/file.shp')
ds = DataSource('/tmp/parent')
```

Answer (score 0):

stringify the world_shp Path object when you pass it to the SourceData constructor "str(world_shp)".

> ds = DataSource(str(world_shp))